# Qt how to change the highlight color of a specific QComboBox item

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I'm trying to make the highlight transparent for a QComboBox. The color of this QComboBox also changes based on the selected index. Here is my best solution so far:

```
switch(comboBox->currentIndex())
{
case 0:
    comboBox->setStyleSheet("QWidget {color:black}");
    break;

case 1:
    comboBox->setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:red; color:white;}");
    break;

case 2:
    comboBox->setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color:green; color:white;}");
    break;
}


comboBox->setItemData(0, QColor(Qt::white), Qt::BackgroundRole);
comboBox->setItemData(0, QColor(Qt::black), Qt::ForegroundRole);
comboBox->setItemData(1, QColor(Qt::red), Qt::BackgroundRole);
comboBox->setItemData(1, QColor(Qt::white), Qt::ForegroundRole);
comboBox->setItemData(2, QColor(Qt::darkGreen), Qt::BackgroundRole);
comboBox->setItemData(2, QColor(Qt::white), Qt::ForegroundRole);

QPalette p = comboBox->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::transparent);
comboBox->setPalette(p);

p = comboBox->view()->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::transparent);

comboBox->view()->setPalette(p);
```

The problem is that whatever color the QComboBox currently is is what the highlight color will be when selecting an item in the popup. I would like each QComboBox item to stay the same color. The images show the problem I'm having.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: I did not understand your problem completely, can you tell what color the items "No change", "Off" an "On" should be and what they are now (or why your images are wrong)?

Comment: Off should be red. On should be green, and No change should be the default color. The highlight color is set to transparent. This works for the combobox, but when you are selecting items in the combobox "transparent" does not give me the results I'm hoping for. You can see in the images the selected item from the QAbstractItemView is always red.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to completely remove highlighted color so the item under mouse cursor would only be distinguished by the dotted frame.

The one way to do this goes as follows: we create class inherited from `QItemDelegate` (Normally simple `QItemDelegate` is responsible for drawing `QComboBox` items). We override paint function like this:

```
class SelectionKillerDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    virtual void paint(QPainter *painter,
        const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
        const QModelIndex &index) const override
     {
         QStyleOptionViewItem myOption = option;
         myOption.state &= (~QStyle::State_Selected);
         QItemDelegate::paint (painter, myOption, index);
     }
 };
```

Basically we're just using normal paint function function but pretend that all the items don't have `QStyle::State_Selected` which is being checked in several functions inside `QItemDelegate::paint`, most importantly in `drawBackground` which is sadly not virtual.

When we're just using `comboBox->setItemDelegate (new SelectionKillerDelegate)` to make our delegate be used instead of simple `QItemDelegate`. That's all.

The good thing is that focused item is determined using `QStyle::State_HasFocus` so dotted frame for item pointed by mouse cursor will still be visible even with this delegate.